# Where is Advertisement.Banner class in Unity Advertisement v2.3.1 package?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ads

I'm implementing Unity Ads in my game, now i'm using Advertisement package v2.3.1 from package manager. I set up rewarded and video ad, but can't do anything with Banner ads.

I set up id in a project dashboard and just call Show function with banner placement id.

```
private IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady()
{
    while (!Advertisement.IsReady(bannerPlacementId))
    {
        yield return delay;
    }
    Debug.Log("Showing Banner");
    ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions {resultCallback = HandleBannerShowResult};
    Advertisement.Show(bannerPlacementId, options);
}
```

As for unity documentation Advertisement namespace have Banner class, but i don't see it in my project. So on android build i don't see any banner or smth, other ads work as expected.